# java try catch block not working using reflection - have no idea why, also maybe a thread error

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, reflection, try-catch

writing a system in netbeans rcp - not sure if this matters, i just don't trust the rcp

We're approaching crunch time on our system and the following error keeps happening (sometimes it happens after 10 minutes, sometimes it runs for 2 days and then happens which is leading me to believe it could be a threading error)

we have a socket reader class which implements runnable - here is a sample of the code

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        try {
           /*
            * can't display actual code
            * reads data through socket and passes stream to a new handler class 
            * which uses reflection to create new object based off socket stream 
            * (none of this happens in a separate thread)
            * (we're not holding a reference to the handler class - a new one is
            * -created every iteration) 
            *
            * at some point during the creation of this object, we get a socket 
            * closed exception happening at SocketInputStream.socketRead()
            */
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

what i expect to happen is that the socket exception should just be caught by the catch block and the cleanup executed

what ends up happening instead is i get a visible stack trace (pops up in the netbeans uncaught exception window and displays in the console) for java.net.SocketException socket closed - i cannot post the stack trace due to customer requirements

what else is strange is that in the actual socket input handler class we have the following method (this is the method that the exception is actually being thrown from)

```
public Abstract________ new________(Class<? extends Abstract________> clazz, 
            DataInput input) {
    ...
    try {
        // reflection code here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("...");
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    ...
}
```

if i try manually throwing the java.net.SocketException after the catch block the exception reads java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException exception: socket closed

yet the stack trace that we receive randomly simply says java.net.SocketException: socket closed

this is leading me to believe that in our socket stream handling class it's not even catching the exception to begin with.

Does anybody have any input as to why this may be happening???

also - i am very sorry that i can't post the actual code, i'm not trying to be cryptic

so far the one thing i'm wondering about - i am somewhat familiar with reflection but not to a great extent - when i manually throw an exception it always gets caught by the try catch block - if an exception is thrown from something in reflection is there any way it could break the try catch contract - i don't see why it would but i mean, i'm honestly not sure and grasping for straws at this point

i have received permission to post an edited stack trace

[image]

in the MessageReader class there is no separate thread - the newMessage method is where the exception is being caught, wrapped into a RuntimeException and thrown up - the ____Reader is the socket reader with the while loop

both methods do show up in the stack trace

not sure if this will help

Comment: I suspect you need to follow the start trace very carefully, as the two exceptions are not passing through the same try/catch block. Exceptions are always caught.

Comment: I know you say nothing is being done in a separate thread. But if you don't have a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler set up you might want to try that, just to make sure. Print the name of the thread and verify it is what you think it should be.

Comment: I am adding this right now, i don't know why we didn't have one in the first place, thank you very much

Comment: so, i'm not sure at all what this means, in the actual socket reader class i set a new uncaught exception handler to just print out the thread and the stack trace - it missed the uncaught exception handler all together and just got thrown all the way up again.... what in the world does that mean????

Answer (score 1):

A thrown Error (java.lang.Error) may be bypassing your catch block (which is only catching Exceptions). Try catching Error and print out whatever debug statements you need. Don't forget to rethrow the error from the catch block.

It could also be that an Exception is being thrown in the catch block.

Comment: right but if the thrown error was bypassing the catch block we'd receive a message for an uncaught error - in this case it is definite that we are receiving an uncaught SocketException

Comment: @sean.exposure could it be an Exception is being thrown by your cleanup() method?

Comment: that's actually a good question - the first line of the cleanup() method is Thread.interrupt() - this is happening before setting the socket to null and closing the socket (also neither the read or cleanup methods are synchronized) - i'm wondering now if there is a possibility this could be whats causing it - from the stack trace i don't believe the exception itself is being thrown from the cleanup but that could definitely be something that's causing it - thanks for the input

Comment: sean.exposure I dont think it would be from your cleanup method because the stack trace would include SocketReader.cleanup(Reader:xxx)

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

- The exception is being caught higher up in the stack trace
- or, the stack trace doesn't actually contain either of the methods you've pasted